# Could not find or load main class called from Linux terminal

Tags: java, linux, terminal, twilio, javac

I am using `javac` to compile a Java program at the CentOS 7 terminal.  The program is very simple and is being used for some testing.  But it is throwing a `could not find or load main class` error as shown below.  How can I resolve this error?

Here is the background:

The Java program is located in `/home/user/javacode/`, and the two jar files it uses as dependencies are in `/home/user/javacode/dependencies`.  The terminal commands and responses from trying to compile and run it are:

```
[user@domain javacode]$ javac -cp .:/home/user/javacode/dependencies/twilio-java-sdk-3.4.5.jar:/home/user/javacode/dependencies/httpcore-4.1.2.jar SendText.java
[user@domain javacode]$ java -cp .:/home/user/javacode/dependencies/twilio-java-sdk-3.4.5.jar:/home/user/javacode/dependencies/httpcore-4.1.2.jar mainpackage.SendText xxxxxxxxxx HelloThere
Error: Could not find or load main class name.of.package.SendText
```

**Is the problem with the compilation syntax, or with the calling syntax?**  Note that `xxxxxxxxxx` and `HelloThere` are two `args` to be sent to the program when it is called. `xxxxxxxxxx` is the phone number to which a text will be sent, and `HelloThere` is the message.  (The code is tested and does send a text if compiled and run correctly.)

`SendText.java` contains 6 imports as follows:

```
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient;
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.factory.MessageFactory;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.Message;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
```

I checked, and all of the 6 imports are located in the following two jars, which I also specified in the commands above:

```
/home/user/javacode/dependencies/twilio-java-sdk-3.4.5.jar
/home/user/javacode/dependencies/httpcore-4.1.2.jar
```

Just to prove that there is a main method in `SendText.java`, the results of `nano SendText.java` are:

```
package name.of.package;

import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient;
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.factory.MessageFactory;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.Message;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SendText {

  public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "arealsid";
  public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "arealtoken";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws TwilioRestException {
    TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
    String to = args[0];
    String body = args[1];
    // Build a filter for the MessageList
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body", body));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", to));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", "+11234567654"));
 
    MessageFactory messageFactory = client.getAccount().getMessageFactory();
    Message message = messageFactory.create(params);
    System.out.println(message.getSid());
  }
}
```

Per @Tyler's comments, I typed the following and got the following responses:

```
[user@domain javacode]$ ls -al
total 12
drwxrwxr-x  3 user user   66 Aug 21 21:19 .
drwxr-xr-x. 6 user user 4096 Aug 21 21:20 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user   63 Aug 21 21:24 dependencies
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user 1495 Aug 21 21:27 SendText.class
-rw-r--r--  1 user user 1313 Aug 21 19:28 SendText.java
[user@domain javacode]$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.5.4.2.el7_0-x86_64 u75-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
[user@domain javacode]$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_75
[user@domain javacode]$ java SendText
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SendText (wrong name: name.of.package/SendText)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
[user@domain javacode]$ java name.of.package.SendText
Error: Could not find or load main class name.of.package.SendText
```

Comment: Are your java and javac from the same Java version? Perhaps your compilation is targeting a newer version of Java than your JRE can handle.

Comment: Also, are .class files generated by your call to javac?

Comment: @Tyler I added the terminal's answers to your questions to the end of my OP.

Comment: What happens if you just run `java SendText`?

Comment: @Tyler I just added the terminal's responses to the end of my OP.

Comment: Have you looked at gradle builds?  It's all CLI, very bare bones, but very powerful.  I don't know how far you can go as a practical matter with javac when dealing with classpath.  Theoretically, sure, why not, but...  **In theory, there is no difference between theory and practice. But, in practice, there is.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a simple test which replicated the error OP demonstrated:

Test.java

```
package com.github.example;

public class Test{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("hello world");
  }
}
```

Compiling: 
    javac Test.java

Running like OP:

```
java com.github.example.Test
Error: Could not find or load main class com.github.example.Test
```

Running like OP without package name:

```
java Test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test (wrong name: com/github/example/Test)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

As suggested by @Javy, I created the directory structure

```
com/github/example
```

And put Test.class in it. Then:

```
mv Test.class com/github/example/
java com.github.example.Test
hello world
```

Comment: Thank you and +1.  It is throwing noClassDefFound errors for apache ClientConnectionManager and TwilioRestException, but I think I may have to research those separately to confirm I have all the required jars before deciding to post another answer.  I assume that this moves me past the error that triggered this posting.

Comment: For the worst case you can comment the package line and run.
`// package com.github.example;`

Answer (score 1):

you shoud make directory according your `package name`

for example

```
package com.peng.test;
public class A {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

The current directory structure is as the following

```
TestJ
   --A.java
```

then you should make directory

```
mkdir bin
```

then compile the `A.java` using the following cmd

```
javac -d bin A.java
```

now the directory like the following

```
TestJ
   --A.java
   --bin
     --com
       --peng
         --test
           --A.class
```

then

```
cd bin
```

then

```
java com.peng.test.A
```